# How to use jssc in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, serial-port

I'm developing a program to measure weight by connecting a PC with an electronic scale.
I'm developing a language with Kotlin, and I'm trying to refer to Java's library, JSSC.

but I don't know what to do because I get a reference error every time.
The development tool is IntelliJ from JetBrain.

```
import jssc.SerialPortList

object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames()
        for (i in portNames.indices) {
            println(portNames[i])
        }
    }
}
```

The top one is a kortlin and the bottom one is a java. I used the translator of the development tool.

```
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
            for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
                System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Java executed, but Kotlin was unable to compile due to errors such as

```
Unresolved reference:jssc 
Unresolved reference: SerialPortList
```

I'm not sure how to avoid these reference errors, so I'm asking for advice.
Please give me a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use [java-native/jssc](https://github.com/java-native/jssc) library. The error `Unresolved reference` is a compilation error. Your code does not have access to the class `jssc.SerialPortList`. You should follow the [instructions on the Github page](https://github.com/java-native/jssc) and add the dependency in your maven or gradle config, or manually add the jar dependency into your Intellij Idea.